# Cannot run npm as root

Tags: linux, node.js, installation, npm, sudo

I am trying to get grunt up and running, by following [this](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started), and I cannot get much further than the first step. I am able to type

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

But this command fails, giving me the advice

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator
```

Ok... now I try to run the same command with sudo

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

And I get the error

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

Which to me, is sort of weird, because my shell was able to recognize npm without the "sudo" thrown in front. How do I install this globally/get sudo to recognize npm as a valid program?

Comment: It's possible that your `$PATH` variable is different between your regular user and your superuser. Run the command `echo $PATH` as your regular user, then run `sudo echo $PATH` and see if the path that contains `npm` is found in both.

Comment: Figured out the answer w the help of a coworker, thanks though :D

Comment: That's great to hear! You should consider posting it as an answer to your own question so that what you learned may be useful to others.

Comment: Already did.. see below

Comment: oops, sorry I missed that - thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer with the help of a co-worker. Basically, there was a file that I did not have permissions on, which I found by looking at the error log. So I sudo'd chmod'd that file with a code of 777, and then ran the npm install command again, and found that it worked. Thought I would paste the answer in case it helps anyone.

Comment: Please could you help me find this file? I'm having this problem too.

Comment: It's been so long. Do you have any npm error logs that I could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$ sudo su
# npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: Also I tried this

which npm : "/usr2/local/bin/npm"
sudo which npm : "which: no npm in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)"

Comment: Try this: $ sudo move /usr/bin/npm /usr/sbin/npm and try what I said. This will move npm to the 'sbin' folder, where you can run it directly from a superuser account. If that doesn't work, retry what you made on the question.

Comment: Should I really be "moving" it, or copying it?